# how to pass data from one page to another page in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern

I am stuck with a problem with passing data from one page to another page in next.js as I am building a basic news application in which I am fetching get requests from news api and I got results of 10 articles and I mapped them correctly but I want to pass the single article date to a new Page named singleNews.  So How can I do it?
here is place where I am fetching all 10 articles:

```
export default function news({data}) {
    // const randomNumber = (rangeLast) => {
    //   return  Math.floor(Math.random()*rangeLast)
    // }
    // console.log(data)

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <h1 className="heading">Top Techcrunch Headlines!</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.newsPage}>
            { // here you always have to check if the array exist by optional chaining
             data.articles?.map(
                (current, index) => {
                    return(
                        <Card datas={current} key={index+current.author} imageSrc={current.urlToImage} title={current.title} author={current.author}/>
                    )
                }
            )
        }
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const response = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=${process.env.NEWS_API_KEY}&pageSize=12`)
    const data = await response.json() // by default Article length is 104
    // const articles =  data.articles;

    return{
        props : {
            data,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer below not work if you sending data as json and didn't want show it in address bar.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can pass data to another page via `Link` component this way:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link
  href={{
    pathname: '/to-your-other-page',
    query: data // the data
  }}
>
  <a>Some text</a>   
</Link>
```

and then receive that data in your other page using `router`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter();
const data = router.query;
```

This is also known as putting state in the URL.

**Update - Next.js v13+:**

Next.js added a new [app](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) directory feature which uses [React Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components) by default. Since Next.js v13.4.1 the `app` directory is now stable and is the recommended way of working with the framework.

Some changes have been implemented on the `Link` component and `useRouter` hook. Also, some new hooks have been added for client-side use. A brief list of these changes:

- It's no longer needed to wrap an `a` tag with the `Link` component. The new `Link` component extends the HTML `<a>` element. `<a>` tag attributes can be added to `Link` as props. For example, `className` or `target="_blank"`. These will be forwarded to the underlying `<a>` element on render.
- The new `useRouter` hook should be imported from `next/navigation` and not `next/router`.
- The query object has been removed and is replaced by [useSearchParams()](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params).

**Passing data from one page to another using `app` directory feature and Server Components:**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const SomePage = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Some page</h1>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: '/anotherpage',
          query: {
            search: 'search'
          }
        }}
      >
        Go to another page
      </Link>
    </section>
  )
}

export default SomePage
```

Receiving the data through `searchParams` prop:

```
const AnotherPage = ({ searchParams }) => {
  console.log(searchParams.search) // Logs "search"

  ...
}

export default AnotherPage
```

**On Client Components:**

```
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

const SomeClientComponent = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  console.log(searchParams.get('search')) // Logs "search"
 
  ...
}

export default SomeClientComponent
```

This also works with page components on `pages` folder. Don't include the `'use client'` directive in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much @ivanatis i got it  and it  is now working

Comment: What if I want to send large data object to another page that I can't display in url.

Comment: @ChandlerBing i think for large data use Context

Comment: I'm using Typescript so it throw error  "Type 'moderatedTestListType' is not assignable to type 'string | ParsedUrlQueryInput | null | undefined'." how to solve in my case?

Comment: @SanskarTiwari what do you mean by context?

Comment: @SteveMoretz React Context API - https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs

Comment: @Shano thanks but how's that passing to another page, it won't be available on the next page after a reload anyways.

Comment: This response should be included in the Next.js docs.

Comment: Please update your answer since this way will showing data in address bar, which is urgly, **this only works on string or int datatype, not json**!!

Comment: @NicholasJela I don't understand? That is the whole point of "putting the state in the URL" and this is also what this answer is referring to: *"This is also known as putting state in the URL."*

Comment: @ivanatias 1. Your sending works only when the data showing in address bar, which means, strings, num can work, but not for other data types, it will be urgly if showing in adress bar, you should mention this; 2. If I were u, I would say further, you can using as to hide it, but you won't able to get the data in destination page, you should also mention it for new comers.