# How to access data passed from a component to a page via <LInk> in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a nextjs app . I have used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221419/14287707  to pass data from a component to a page using the Link like this.

```
                <Link href={{
                  pathname: "/products/"+id,
                  query: userId // the data
                }}>  
                  <a>Show more</a>
                </Link>
```

So I am able to see the extra data that I have passed on the receiving page as an object like this,
**[id].tsx**

```
const router = useRouter();
const data  = router.query;

  console.log("USER ID IS!!!!!!", data)
```

but the console log gives me the value with an empty key like this

```
{990:""
id: "12"}
```

It also gets appended on the url like this

```
products/12?990
```

How can I access the 990 ? eg I can get the id like this data.id . But what about the userId ?

Comment: What is the name of the file where you have this code? It should be a dynamic route

Comment: The file is [id].tsx .@TusharShahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current url is `products/12?990`. It should ideally be `products/12?userId=990`. The reason for that is that you are passing a primitive string like `query: userId`, which translates to `query: 990`.

You are supposed to pass an object according to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object) like :

```
 query: { userId : userId }
```

or simply:

```
 query: { userId }
```