# How to pass data from one page to another

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Start Game

I have this code and I have page.js in game folder, and I have to use useEffect in this game page so I can fetch data with passed states. how can I get passed data in query in game page

how can I get passed data in query in game page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221255/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-next-js This might help you

Comment: Use the url as state