# How to pass data between pages in NextJs 14

Tags: next.js, navigation, router

Please guys I'm new to this don't be harsh.
I'm trying to pass data in nextJs and I have followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221419/22939076)

After following the answer, I get this error  `Uncaught TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function` and more errors trying to solve it.

Here is what I have done.

###### Page A

```js
const handleNavigate = (campaign) => {
    // router.push(`/campaign-details/${campaign.pId}`, { state: campaign });
    router.push({
      pathname: `/campaign-details/${campaign.pId}`,
      query: {
        owner: campaign.owner,
        name: campaign.name,
        title: campaign.title,
        description: campaign.description,
        target: campaign.target,
        deadline: campaign.deadline,
        amountCollected: campaign.amountCollected,
        image: campaign.image,
        pId: campaign.pId,
      },
    });
  };

..........................

        {!isLoading &&
          campaigns.length > 0 &&
          campaigns.map((campaign) => (
            <FundCard
              key={uuidv4()}
              {...campaign}
              handleClick={() => handleNavigate(campaign)}
            />
          ))}
```

This is supposed to pass state to other component when a use navigates. After that page B below, takes the data passed and displays the component from the clicked card on a full page.

###### Page B

```js
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

// example usecase

            <div>
              <h4 className="  font-semibold text-[18px] text-white uppercase">
                {searchParams.get(title)}
              </h4>

              <p className="mt-[3px]   font-normal text-[16px] leading-[18px] text-[#808191]">
                {searchParams.get(category)}
              </p>
            </div>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

From all the answers I have found, most were outdated but this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221419/22939076) seemed to be most relevant to my issue. As shown above, I have tried to implement it but it gives me more errors probably because of something I'm doing wrong. I need help, please.

Comment: @ivanatias Sir. help out if you can please.